# Generating Java code using Xtend and Sirius

Tags: emf, xtend, eclipse-sirius

So, my aim is to create graphical DSL. I created a ecore model using Eclipse Modeling Framework, after that I've used Sirius to create graphical modeling tool and I have problems with the last step which is generating Java code. I would like to use Xtend to generate it. Any suggestions what would be the best way to do it, or some helpful links ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects:

1. the Xtend generator itself, which can be developed and tested indepently of Sirius. It will take as input your DSL files/models (not the `.aird` or `.odesign` files from Sirius) and produce whatever you want. I can't help on this aspect.
2. integration of the generation with the Sirius-based modeler.

Assuming you know how to programatically invoke the Xtend generator, there are several ways to trigger it from inside Sirius. For example you can use the [Popup Menu](http://www.eclipse.org/sirius/doc/specifier/diagrams/Diagrams.html#tools_specification) type of tool to add an entry to the context menu of your modeler, which can then call any Java code you want, and launch the generator from there.

This is what [Ecore Tools](http://eclipse.org/ecoretools) does to launch the EMF GenModel code gen: [it declares the popup menu](https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/ecoretools/org.eclipse.ecoretools/+/master/org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools.design/description/ecore.odesign#196) which invokes [this Java class](https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/ecoretools/org.eclipse.ecoretools/+/master/org.eclipse.emf.ecoretools.design.ui/src/org/eclipse/emf/ecoretools/design/ui/action/GenerateAllAction.java) to perform the actual generation.

Comment: Well when I create instance for my ecore model and specify a viewpoint for it using sirius in .odesign file, I would like to generate code from the diagram I create using that viewpoint.

Comment: I am stuck on the generation of the code from my DSL file using Xtend, Could you provide any link to some content that could help me with that.